# Implementing liftM2 in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For an exercise, I've been trying to implement liftM2 using just the functions ap and liftM. The functions are defined as:

```
ap :: IO (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
liftM :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b

liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
```

I can easily do liftM2 using do notation but not sure how to do it using just ap and liftM. I was thinking of having the result be something that looks like this:

```
liftM2 f a b = liftM (_) (ap _ a)
```

I'm confused on how to mess with f, which is (a -> b -> c) such that I can just turn a to b and b to c. Thank you.

Comment: How about switch the order of `liftM` and `ap`?

Comment: Where does that exercise come from? `liftM*` and `ap` are pretty much obsolete, the modern versions are `fmap`/`liftA*` and `<$>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general pattern is transforming

```
liftMn f a1 ... an
```

into

```
f <$> a1 <*> ... <*> an
-- i.e., more precisely
(... ((f <$> a1) <*> a2) ... <*> an)
```

where `<$>` is `liftM` (AKA `fmap`) and `<*>` is `ap`.

Hence, for `n=2` we get

```
(f `liftM` a1) `ap` a2
-- i.e.
ap (liftM f a1) a2
```

Checking the types:

```
f :: t1 -> t2 -> r
liftM f :: IO t1 -> IO (t2 -> r)
a1 :: IO t1
liftM f a1 :: IO (t2 -> r)
ap (liftM f a1) :: IO t2 -> IO r
a2 :: IO t2
ap (liftM f a1) a2 :: IO r
```

The key idea here is to read `f :: t1 -> t2 -> r` as `f :: t1 -> (t2 -> r)` so that `liftM f :: IO t1 -> IO (t2 -> r)` follows. Note the function type inside the `IO`. We can then "distribute" `IO` over `->` using `ap`, so that we can apply `a2 :: IO t2`.

Comment: Thanks for explicitly noting the key idea. It is really insightful to consider $f$ working on just one argument as returning another function, which in turn expects a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth noting that your initial guess,

```
liftM2 f a b = liftM (_) (ap _ a)
```

isn't really that far off. But `ap` isn't quite the right place to start for that shape. Rather, consider

```
pairIO :: IO a -> IO b -> IO (a, b)
pairIO m n = do
  a <- m
  b <- n
  return (a, b)
```

Now, you can write

```
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
liftM2 f m n = liftM _ (pairIO m n)
```

GHC will tell you that it needs

```
_ :: (a, b) -> c
```

and you should be able to fill that very easily.

This actually reflects a common alternative formulation of the notion of an "applicative Functor":

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  pur :: a -> f a
  pair :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

This class turns out to be equivalent in power to the standard `Applicative` class.

---

It turns out that you can actually combine actions in various ways, thanks to the `Monoidal` associative law. This looks like

```
xs `pair` (ys `pair` zs) = jigger <$> ((xs `pair` ys) `pair` z's)
   where
     jigger ((x, y), z) = (x, (y, z))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `ap :: IO (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b`, we have both

```
  IO (a -> b)         {- and -}       IO (a -> b -> c)
  IO  a                               IO  a
  -----------                         ----------------
  IO       b                          IO      (b -> c)
```

thus we can combine two IO values with an IO binary function through

```
ap2 :: IO (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
ap2 mf mx my = ap mf mx `ap` my

             IO (a -> b -> c)
             IO  a
             ----------------
             IO      (b -> c)
             IO       b
             ----------------
             IO            c
```

or with a pure binary function,

```
liftM2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO b -> IO c
liftM2 f mx my = ap2 (return f) mx my
               = ap (return f) mx `ap` my
               = (ap . return) f mx `ap` my
```

And what is the type of `ap . return`?

```
> :t ap . return
ap . return :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Why, it's the type of `liftM`! (here a more specific `(a -> b -> c) -> IO a -> IO (b -> c)`)

```
              = liftM f mx `ap` my
```